# Why does customer see high voltage on my PNP sensor output?

Tags: noise, output

I have designed a capacitive sensor with a PNP output. The output stage is a Sziklai pair, as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNE2o6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

While the circuit works OK, one of my customers have measured the DC voltage on the output node (the multimeter works well) as 40V when the output is off, and 80V when the output is on. (He touches the output probe while doing so) I am fully assured that this is noise, and this will flow when the output is connected to a load, but it is hard to convince the customer which will connect this to a sensitive input. We didn't notice this effect during our tests in our noise free laboratory.

The customer has access to terminals VDD, GND and PNP_OUT.

My questions are:

1. What causes this effect?
2. Can this really cause damage to the connected devices?
3. What can I do to prevent this from happening, without breaking the reverse polarity protection on the output?

Comment: Have you tested this to confirm? And did your tests show the same behavior?

Comment: @SolarMike In our laboratory, no. But the customer sent a video about it.

Comment: Precisely what terminals does the customer have access to? Show them all and indicate which terminals were used for the measurement.

Comment: @Andyaka hello Andy, schematic edited.

Comment: to answer question 3, you could add a large resistor (500k or more) between the PNP out and GND, after the diode

Comment: Maybe they are measuring using AC on the multimeter? Can they directly measure the 24 volts - do they have access (I'm assuming not else you would have shown that as per my earlier request).

Comment: Where in the circuit is the "capacitive sensor"? is it a piezoelectric device? Or is there any chance you have built an unintentional voltage doubler?

Comment: @BrianDrummond this is only the output stage. The device uses PIC microcontroller's capacitive sensing library and it uses two traces to make a measurement. About voltage doubler, I don't know the circuit, will check.

Comment: And are the grounds of the sensor and the other device connected properly?

Comment: It could be a ground loop or maybe the long wires acts like an antenna, picking up noise from mains.